# How to solve the Error: Cannot find module '../graphql/queries.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations' in an angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, import, graphql

I'm working on a serverless app with amplify and angular on AWS. and I'm trying to get information from a DynamoDB table. I'm following a very basic tutorial from AWS to run a simple query using GraphQL from a frontend app using angular. I have a problem with the next imports:

```
import * as queries from '../graphql/queries';

import { ListRestaurants } from '../graphql/queries.graphql';
```

I getting this error:

> Error: src/app/app.component.ts:9:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find
> module '../graphql/queries.graphql' or its corresponding type
> declarations.

This is the image of the error:

[image]

any advice would be great.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

in my case ***import {xxx} from "graphql/urql"***, after change it to ***import {xxx} from "urql"***, error gone and code works.

Also, while searching online to solve the problem, I found a discussion which might help you:
[fix(deps): include "graphql" as a dependency #1381](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/pull/1381)